# How do I fill na values in a column with the average of previous non-na and next non-na value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

Raw table:

| Column A |
| --- |
| 5 |
| nan |
| nan |
| 15 |

New table:

| Column A |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 10 |
| 15 |

Comment: for this specific example : ``df.fillna(df.mean())``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be the following (using `fillna` twice (with options `ffill` and `bfill`) and then averaging them):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 15]})
filled_series = [df['x'].fillna(method=m) for m in ('ffill', 'bfill')]
print(pd.concat(filled_series, axis=1).mean(axis=1))
# 0     5.0
# 1     5.0
# 2    10.0
# 3    10.0
# 4    15.0
```

As you can see, this works even if `nan` happens at the beginning or at the end.